# given a database, how do you generate CRUD forms for Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, crud

given a database schemas, is it possible to automatically generate forms for crud operations on the tables?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to whether you are good to use any frameworks apart from standard J2EE (like spring/jsf etc)? Also if you are not happy with the answers, then add comments to them asking more info or add more info to your questions. Nobody can help anybody if nobody is specific in what he asks anybody.

Comment: J2EE? Are you sure? Don't you mean Java EE?

Comment: i have about 10 users editable tables, and instead of doing the CRUD manually ... i am looking for tools that can help me generate them. 

Something like maybe http://nakedobjects.org/ which automatically generate the tables for editing. But i need to be a java web app. 

it's going to take me a while to learn all these frameworks and accept one out the 4 answers below ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use Telosys Tools, an Eclipse plugin working from an existing database with customizable Velocity templates

Just plug your database, and get some templates availables on GitHub.
There are templates for Spring Data, AngularJS, JPA...

See: https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Seam](http://seamframework.org), and using [seam-gen](http://relation.to/Bloggers/UsingASeamgenProjectInJBossTools) it can generate an entire functional crud for you by providing a database.

Comment: looks hopeful ... any hints on how to do it with glassfish V3 ? i am hoping not to deploy another webapp.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult. I know there where some work being done to make this work nicely on Glassfish V3. But I haven't tried it my self. But I am pretty sure it works fine, as many forum postings are about people using Seam with Glassfish

Answer (score 1):

[MetaWidget](http://www.metawidget.org/) was designed for this.

Given that the JPA model contains almost all information necessary for a basic CRUD interface, it's astonishing that there are only so few implementations.

Comment: anything that bundles OIM with ORM together ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you mean by J2EE, [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) might be worth a look.